# How to maximize the use of computer performance Core i7

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, productivity

How to maximize the use of computer performance Core i7 960 / 12GB Ram?. My operating system is Debian 6 (Linux kernel - 3.0.0-1-amd64). I think it does not work very quickly. Looking for some ways to increase productivity, may be that the system is loaded into memory at once, then it will be faster? It may be necessary to use some features of the processor? In general, I need advice.

Comment: Hi, Grigorij. There are enough ways of increasing computer performance to create a separate wiki - please narrow down your question.

Comment: There are enough ways to increase computer performance to fill a whole internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you think your computer is running slow check that your IDE/SATA drives are configured correctly.  If your hard drive is defaulting to progammed I/O it is probably running an order of magnitude slower than it should be.  Tuning parmaters with [hdparm(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm) lets you set this up properly.

I don't know how much of a problem this is with modern kernels and chipset support, but it still seems to make its appearance in forums on a semi-regular basis.  It used to be a significant problem with linux installs and was pretty much the first port of call if somebody complained about a new linux install running slow.

It might be worth looking into - a howto can be found [here.](http://technomancer.me.uk/howto-hdparm-linux-disk-tuning)

Answer (score 1):

Read lots of books / online references. Gather lots of data. Run tests. Change things. Gather more data. Repeat.

There's no quick answer.